# Python Idiom for Boolean Evaluation of Assignment

Tags: python

I have the following C program as an example of what I would like to be able to do in python:

```
foo@foo:~/$ cat test.c 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool get_false(){
    return false;
}

bool get_true(){
    return true;
}

void main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    bool x, y;

    if ( x = get_false() ){
        printf("Whiskey. Tango. Foxtrot.\n");
    }   

    if ( y = get_true() ){
        printf("Nothing to see here, keep moving.\n");
    }   
}
foo@foo:~/$ gcc test.c -o test
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:13: warning: return type of ‘main’ is not ‘int’
foo@foo:~/$ ./test 
Nothing to see here, keep moving.
foo@foo:~/$
```

In python, the only way I know how to do this is:

```
foo@foo:~/$ cat test.py
def get_false():
    return False

def get_true():
    return True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = get_false()
    if x:
        print "Whiskey. Tango. Foxtrot."

    y = get_true()
    if y:
        print "Nothing to see here, keep moving."

    #if (z = get_false()):
    #    print "Uncommenting this will give me a syntax error."

    #if (a = get_false()) == False:
    #    print "This doesn't work either...also invalid syntax."
foo@foo:~/$ python test.py
Nothing to see here, keep moving.
```

Why?  Because I'd like to be able to say:

```
if not (x=get_false()): x={}
```

Basically I'm working around a bad API where the type returned is either a dict when data is available, or False.  Yes, a valid answer would be to return consistent types and to use Exceptions instead of False for a failure mode indicator.  I can't change the underlying API though, and I run into this pattern quite a bit in environments like Python with dynamic typing (read: without strict typing for function/method interfaces).

Any suggestions on how to reduce the if/else overhead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use

```
x = get_false() or {}
```

Should `get_false()` return a `False` value, Python will return the second operand of `or`.

See [section 5.10](http://docs.python.org/release/2.6.8/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations) of the Python reference manual. (It's been there since [at least Python 2.0](http://docs.python.org/release/2.0/ref/lambda.html)).

Comment: Define newer...3+ ?  A link to the changelog would be helpful, thanks.

Comment: I've edited my answer. It's been there since at least version 2.0, which is (hopefully) the absolute earliest version of Python you have to worry about.

Answer (score 1):

You are compounding an inconvenient API with repetitive bad patch up code thus compounding the problem that you seek to avoid.

```
def wrapper():
    x = get_false()
    if not x:
        x = dict()
    return x
```

Then your code isn't littered with hard-to-read ternary (or ternary-like) operations and you can change wrapper to raise exceptions if you find that more suitable.

What you can't do is have an assignment as a conditional as in C; Python doesn't do that.

Comment: Well, more generally, expressions of any form cannot contain assignments.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Python [ternary operator](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) for this:

```
>>> data=False    # could be data=readyourapi()
>>> x=data if data else {}
>>> x
{}
```

Comment: That's just as long as `data = func(); if not data: data = {}`

Comment: @nneonneo: I don't think the number of characters is the test. It is how readable it is by third parties (or yourself in a few months)

Comment: I'd consider `data = func(); if not data: data = {}` to be reasonably readable, at least equivalent to the ternary solution. `data = func() or {}` is somewhat more cryptic, but a standard idiom in many other languages (e.g. Perl, Ruby, JS). It's just not needed as often in Python.

Comment: @nneonneo: agreed. btw, I think you answer is very good (and i voted for it). i offer this as an alternative. it is just personal preference of what you would rather read after a while